# What projection to use to create aligned GB and Ireland OS Grid map

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, grids-graticules

I would like to create a map like the following:

[image]

It displays the 100km grid square systems used by both UK and Ireland.

I have created the 100km grid squares using the TomBio tools plug in, however, the issue I'm having is with finding a projection over both the UK and Ireland that ensures the grid squares align up as in the image above with neither Ireland of UK rotated such as in the image below, which happens when using either 27700 or 29902. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: In the map you show the grids do not align north. They just align up. https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/blog/2019/03/magnetic-north-continues-its-march-to-the-east/

Comment: Yeah, I should have worded that better, have edited to make that clear

Comment: You could create a new grid, like BNG, just move the origin